# Online text editor like one used in StackExchange

Tags: open-source, web-development, text-editor

I am looking for an online text editor to integrate into my website.

The Editor should be same as used in StackExchange sites while editing posts, Is the text editor in StackExchange sites open source, if not are there any open source alternative for this ?

It should have Code highlighter feature, and basic text editing features like bold, italics, blockquote, etc. – and must allow to be used on a commercial website.

Comment: SE sites use [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/), which produces [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) content. So what format should the editor you want to use support?

Comment: @Izzy Is stackEdit opensource? Can i use it in my commercial website without any charges?

Comment: It is open source, yes. I don't know about commercial use (and your question didn't ask for that (I've just added that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ever need just plain text the simplest solution is to use [Schrib](https://shrib.com)

[image: Shrib]

But for what you described, I recommend [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/editor).

- It has code highlighting
- Bold, italics, underline, quotes, images, HTML...
- Uses pretty much the same syntax as StackExchange
- Nice design
- Has it's source code [here](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit).

[image: StackEdit]

Also if you only need to include it in your website you can use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) (also open source). It is designed to be included in websites so you can just copy-paste the thing into the website and it would work.

Comment: Is StackEdit open source, I,e can I use it in my commercial website?

Comment: @Sandeep Yes it's open source. Answer updated.